# mysql same price mismatch column value

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon everyone,

I wonder if I can get help with this example in a database.

I have listings delivered as:

```
------------------------------------
|   Id  |   name        |   price  |
-------------------------------
|    1  |   Hawaii      |   20.58  |

|    2  |   Hawaii VIP  |   45.58  |

|    3  |   Aruba       |   13.58  |

|    4  |   Aruba VIP   |   34.58  |

|    5  |   Japon       |   14.58  |

|    6  |   Japon VIP   |   34.58  |

|    7  |   Alemania    |   14.58  |

|    8  |   Alemania VIP   |   14.58  |
```

But I need them to be shown as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   Id  |   name        |   price basic   | price vip
-----------------------------------------------------
|    1  |   Hawaii      |   20.58         |   45.34  |

|    5  |   Japon       |   14.58         |  34.58   |
```

etc etc etc

What I need are the two prices of the same country in a different column in the same query.

As I can catch the "VIP" based on this field and put it in a column with its value

Comment: It would be better to store IS_VIP as a separate column in the first table instead of adding it to the name.

Comment: I am partially in agreement with @GolezTrol. A properly normalised version of this would have a table A listing the names, and a second table B listing the primary key of A which corresponds to the correct name, a boolean corresponding to whether or not you are listing the price for a VIP, and the price. Forgetting the disk space benefit for very large tables, this also removes errors that might be caused by typos in user input and makes queries easier to deal with.

Comment: And instead of a boolean you could consider a price type, because soon you may have a third type.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to store IS_VIP as a separate column in the first table instead of adding it to the name, but since it's not a perfect world, you could solve it like this until then. :)

```
SELECT
  t.Id,
  t.name,
  t.price as "price basic",
  v.price as "price VIP"
FROM YourTable t
JOIN YourTable v ON v.name = CONCAT(t.name, ' VIP')
```

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/148fe/1)

Comment: golez the OP changed the requirement, add `MIN()` to your prices and `GROUP BY t.name` to satisfy the request :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I don't see where they request that. It looks like they still need the amounts per country, with the VIP price in a separate column. -edit- I see the answer/new question now.

Comment: golez.. look at the other "answer" its not an answer but an added part to the question by the OP

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it. But I'm not going to answer that. My answer answers the question. It would be very confusing if I answered another answer. :) OP can ask a new question using the "Ask question" button at the right top of the page.